# Unable to bind event to dynamically appended image element

Tags: jquery

I have a below code to access my dynamically added image to delete the row. However I didn't get any `alert`. added html structure. Please check.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".popup-trigger", function (e) {
 //Some code to get some input 
  
       
  //Call PopulateTable2 servlet to get the Inspection row details
  $.ajax({
   url : 'PopulateTable2',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({"inspinp" :inspinp}),
         contentType: 'application/json',
         mimeType: 'application/json',
   success : function(responseJson) {   
    if(responseJson.length!=0){
     if(responseJson && responseJson[0] && responseJson[0].actual1) {
      // find reponseJson as actual values; if found, then made that as read only(i.e., inspection data exist)
      $("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
      $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['parameters']);
        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['specifications']);
        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['actual1']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['actual2']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['actual3']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['actual4']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['actual5']); 
        rowNew.appendTo(tableinsp);
        }); 
      $("#addrow").hide();
      $("#save").hide();
      $("p").hide();     
     }else {
      // else, received response only criteria from QC_CRITERIA table and made it as user editable form
      $("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
      $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['parameters']);
        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['specifications']);
        rowNew.children().eq(2).html('');
        rowNew.children().eq(3).html('');
        rowNew.children().eq(4).html('');
        rowNew.children().eq(5).html('');
        rowNew.children().eq(6).html('');
        rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del">'); // delete image add
        rowNew.appendTo(tableinsp);
        }); 
      $("#addrow").show();
      $("#save").show();
      $("p").show(); 
     } 
    // return false;
    }else{
     $("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
     $('#tab_logic tbody').append('<tr><td>....</td><td><img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del"></td></tr>'); // here also i am adding delete image
     $("#addrow").show();
     $("#save").show();
     $("p").show();  
    }
   }
     });
   
  //unbind all event triggers
  $(".popup").unbind();
  
  // Popup Window
   
});
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").live("click", "#tab_logic.del", function() { 
 alert("i am"); 
});
</script>
<!-- dynamic value will be loaded in pop-up.js -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<!parent table elements -->
<div class="popup">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="tab_logic" >
<tr>
 <th align="center">Parameters</th>
 <th align="center">Specification</th>
 <th align="center">Actual1</th>
 <th align="center">Actual2</th>
 <th align="center">Actual3</th>
 <th align="center">Actual4</th>
 <th align="center">Actual5</th>
 <th align="center">Remove</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add more relevant code like your html, and the code that created the dynamic content

Comment: Sorry. added a code . Actually i am adding in popup window. Please check it.

Comment: Assuming you have only one `#tab_logic` element in the DOM, what you have should work fine

Comment: Are you actually able to see the delete image being created? If you click on it do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: can you add the html structure where you are adding it ? ?

Comment: @ManuelCheța: yes i could see the image, but i didnt receive any error on console

Comment: @kavi your second code does not contain the first. How and where do you run that?

Comment: @LajosArpad: as mentioned above i am appending rows to table tab_logic in 3 ways. 1. There will not be any delete image ; all the data will be loaded from table --> in this case user cant edit the data. 2. only few table cell will be loaded from table data, so user edit rest of the row/cell and they can delete the row alos--> thats why i added delete image to do that process. 3. in this case, there wont be any data, so i have a fresh table row where user can feed their data --> in this case also i have to do delete row -- so i have added an image

Comment: @kavi you misunderstood the question. I was wondering about how do you add the event handler. Can you show me the full script containing your first three-liner?

Comment: @LajosArpad: sorry please check the edited snippet

Comment: @kavi, #tab_logic.del will find tags having the id of tab_logic and the del class as well. Since tags having del class are descendants of tab_logic, you need the space in the selector: #tab_logic .del. Also, live is deprecated, use on instead. Finally, it would not hurt to wrap a $(function() {}) around your three-liner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138010/discussion-between-kavi-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `click` handler should work, provided that:

- you have already included jquery when the handler is created with jquery
- `body` already exists when the handler is being created
- the `else` wrapped around the code you have there actually runs, not a similar code (but without the event handler) in the `if`
- the Javascript code is not crashing before the handler is being created

EDIT:

Based on the edit done just before the time of this edit, we have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").live("click", "#tab_logic.del", function() { 
    alert("i am"); 
});
</script>
```

The main problem is that the selector is looking for tags having the `id` of `tab_logic` and the class of `del` at the same time, however, this does not comply to the structure pattern of `tab_logic` having descendant tags with the `del` class. We need a space there. Also, `live` is deprecated and will not work when you upgrade jquery to version 3, `on` is recommended instead. Finally it would not hurt to wrap a `$(function() {})` around the three-liner above.

Suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del", function() { 
        alert("i am"); 
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. i tried with above but no luck:(

Comment: @kavi are there Javascript errors in the console of your web-browser? Can you run a console.log("#tab_logic").length; just before adding the handler to see whether the item exists?

Comment: please check the image

Comment: @kavi those are warnings. It seems there are no errors. Was the console opened when you started loading the page? Do you see the changes when you check the page source? Have you tried the console.log suggested in my previous comment? If so, what was the result?

Comment: Sure. will post you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the click event to complete document use the specific class or id as selectors like by adding id value to your popup class in div (assuming popup class is used at multiple places and we don't want to add event to all of them)

like:

```
<div class="popup" id="newid">
```

now add the event listener as :

```
$("#newid").on("click", "#tab_logic.del", function() { 
    alert("i am"); 
});
```

now if you click on the image added as you wanted, it generates an alert.

Comment: thanks! but not when click on a row. should trigger when click on an image in table cell